# Boundary conditions of ODE are derivatives, constant falls out

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve an ordinary differential equation, and I have the fundamental solution, but do not know how to get the constants.

The solution is $ T(r)=Ar^2+C_1\ln(r)+C_2$,

I have the conditions $\left.\frac{dT}{dr}\right|_{r=r_i}=B$ and $\left.\frac{dT}{dr}\right|_{r=r_o}=D$

where $r_i$ and $r_o$ are the inner and outer radius.

I took $\frac{dT}{dr}= 2Ar+\frac{C_1}{r}$ with $r=r_i$ to find $C_1$ but have no idea how to find $C_2$.

My thought was to integrate as $\int\frac{dT}{dr}dr=\int D dr =Dr = T(r)$ then evaluate at $r = r_o$ but do not think this is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both boundary conditions are on the derivative, and $C_2$ is an additive constant, which therefore does not appear in the derivative, you cannot determine $C_2$ from the data.

(But you get two conditions for $C_1$, and if they are incompatible, there is no solution at all – unless you also get to choose $A$.)

Comment: Full disclosure, this came out on an engineering problem, so you are saying that the specific, constant free solution can't be found if that is all I have for data? (I guess I expected that, but I would really like to have another way)

Comment: If I am correct, you get $C_1=r_i(B - 2Ar_i)=r_o(D - 2Ar_o)$ where $B$ and $D$ are different.

Comment: Ups, you're right of course. I delete my silly comment. In my defense, I can only note that the number of distractions here was overwhelming. It seems that distracted mathematics is as dangerous as distracted driving.

Comment: No worries, and I get the distracting environment, math like programming really needs a lot of working memory and nothing to flush your mental buffers (distract you).